# Reading indexedDB data and file in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, indexeddb

I'm trying to locate where IE 11 is storing indexedDB file(s). Does anyone know the location?

Futhermore, in Chrome, I'm able to look at the indexedDB via developer tools, navigate the different stores and query the database.

Does anyone know if IE 11 offers this capability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Debugging in IE, you can use an external library as described here -http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/01/25/debugging-indexeddb-applications.aspx

You need to embed an iframe in your application, from where you can see the data.

Your files of IndexedDB are stored at this position:

```
C:\Users\{Your-User-Name}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Indexed DB
```

Comment: I can't believe it's been 3 years since that blog article was written and it's still the #1 search result for an IndexedDb viewer for IE. Not to mention the fact that it requires an iFrame **inside of your project itself**. Facepalm. C'mon Microsoft.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that the link to said [IDBExplorer package](http://dev.modern.ie/testdrive/) points to a completely different source with no actual package.

Comment: @DannyBullis make that 5 and a half years... :/

Comment: Yeah, let's make it six years, juste because...Unbelievable !