# Reading/editing IndexedDB data for IE11

Tags: indexeddb, internet-explorer-11

Trying to view the contents of IndexedDB files for IE 11, and inject more data manually. Adding an iframe as suggested in [Reading indexedDB data and file in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530536/reading-indexeddb-data-and-file-in-ie-11) post is not a good option since the code will be released to production, and ideally I would be able to manipulate the file on demand.

I can open the IE11 IndexedDB files from 
    C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Indexed DB
location, but the files have an irregular encoding, and can't be viewed from a text editor.
Please suggest how to view and edit the content for the indexedDB files without the embedded iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the IndexedDB API, that's what it's for. Trying to edit the database outside of the browser is a bad idea. **A really bad idea**.

The file is not a plain text file, it's a binary file, representing an [ESENT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Storage_Engine) database so no text editor will be able to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the F12 tools to not have a resource viewer like the Chrome tools. You will need to use the API to view and update the data. You can execute the API from the console's command line.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try my indexeddb viewer I have build. More information on [my blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20171114155542/http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2012/11/indexeddbviewer-take-look-inside-your.html) about it.

Comment: Please consider improving or deleting this answer. It is currently very low quality, considering it is linking to something (presumably) outdated in a non-existent blog post, with no information in the answer itself.